# $setPristine() is not working

Tags: html, angularjs

I've a form which has 6 controls(Id, Title, Genre.....) for user to add an entry. Have 2 buttons one of which will add the entry and other will cancel it.

I've written $setPristine() in my cancel button click event in my controller

```
 $scope.reset = function () {
    var master = { Movid: '' }; //Movid--> <input type="text" name="Movid"
    var master1 = { MovTitle: '' };
    var master2 = { MovGnre: '' };
    var master3 = { MovClafictn: '' };
    var master4 = { MovRate: '' };
    var master5 = { MovDate: '' };
    $scope.temp = angular.copy(master);
    $scope.temp1 = angular.copy(master1);
    $scope.temp2 = angular.copy(master2);
    $scope.temp3 = angular.copy(master3);
    $scope.temp4 = angular.copy(master4);
    $scope.temp5 = angular.copy(master5);
    $scope.adduserform.$setPristine();
}
```

But when i click the Cancel button, only validation messages have reset and the values which are in controls still present with them.

Version i'm using
/*
 AngularJS v1.3.14
 (c) 2010-2014 Google, Inc. http://angularjs.org
 License: MIT
*/

Is anything error in my code?????

Comment: only values which are invalid would be present... valid values would get cleared

Comment: No valid values also holding with control @entre